# Retrieve mysql data base value into array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to retrieve the mysql database value into array using java.If I retrieve Student Name from mysql Database means How can I get The all Student name in a mysql table to array using java?give me some examples.

thanks in advance

Comment: Since you'd retrieve DB results into an array the exact same way in the command line or a servlet as in Swing, we can conclude this problem has *nothing* to do with Swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ArrayList<T>` to store name from database and later you may convert it to `String[]` using `List.toArray()` method.

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
    list.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is right question on SO, it seems you've not tried anything :(

Btw, have a look at this first : [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

First query all the student names from DB, then

```
 while(resultset.next(){
            //add each of them to array
       }
```